No Audio: Ubuntu on Zenbook Pro 14 Duo (UX8402)
I have an Asus Zenbook Pro 14 Duo (UX8402VV) that hasn't had audio working in any Ubuntu since I bought it in August of 2023. I'm now using Ubuntu 24.04 and the problem has persisted. Asus seems to have a reputation for this broken audio in Linux on a lot of their laptops.
I can see the audio signal is working fine at the system level, including while using pavucontrol, so I assume this is a kernel/hardware issue just like is plaguing a lot of other Asus laptops.
I've tried fixes listed for other Asus models, but none of them work for my hardware.
I am also on the latest Linux kernel (6.8.7) which didn't help.
Here is a look at some relevant system information:
$ inxi -SMA
...
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Raptor Lake-P/U/H cAVS driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-2: NVIDIA driver: snd_hda_intel
  API: ALSA v: k6.8.7 status: kernel-api
  Server-1: PipeWire v: 1.0.5 status: active`

$ lspci
...
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 22be (rev a1)


trying to reboot the computer generaly solve the problem , but in your case maybe the speakers have a problem contact Asus support team for more information about that

It's definitely not a reboot issue as many Asus models are having the same issue with Linux. There is no support for some of their hardware built into the kernels. Unfortunately Asus has left Linux users to fend for their own up until now. They have nice looking machines but IDK if I'll buy another. Lenovo on the other hand continues to be highly compatible with Linux.

Had similar issue on my UX482 running dual boot with Win 11.
Problem was that Windows when started somehow "locked" all audio outputs and when I restarted laptop back to Ubuntu, I couldn't get it to work. Even though everything looked correct.
To this day I don't know what's causing this. All I know is a workaround that works every time.
Tried updating and downgrading kernel, changing sound servers between PulseAudio and PipeWire and I don't even know what else and nothing worked. Seems like the issue is under the OS layer.
WORKAROUND for me is booting to BIOS after leaving Windows.
For example, when I need to use Windows, I restart my laptop, select Win and use it normally. When I'm done using it, I restart the laptop and instead of selecting either Win or Linux, I need to choose booting to BIOS. Once it starts, I can exit the bios immediately without touching anything there and go again in the boot menu. I can then choose my linux distro and sound works right.
Beside this I never had any other issues regarding audio on ubuntu. Hope this is not OT.
